.NET MAUI Named Pipe Client Stuck on ConnectAsync on MacOS
I'm trying to implement named pipes in .NET MAUI (.NET 8) on Windows and MacOS. Everything works fine when testing on Windows, but when I test it on MacOS, the client gets stuck on connecting.
Pipe Client
namespace Client;

public partial class ClientPage : ContentPage {
    private readonly NamedPipeClientStream _pipeClient;
    private readonly StreamString ss;
    private bool _isConnected = false;

    public ClientPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        _pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", PipeDirection.In, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
        ss = new StreamString(_pipeClient);

        InitPipeClient();
    }

    private async void InitPipeClient() {
        Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] Initializing client");

        if (_isConnected) {
            Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] Already connected to server");
            return;
        }

        Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] hasn't connected yet");

        if (!_pipeClient.IsConnected) {
            Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] is not connected, connecting...");
            await _pipeClient.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // <-- Gets stuck here
            Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] Connected!");
        }

        Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] Connected to server");
        _isConnected = true;

        ListenForMessages();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing() {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        _pipeClient.Close();
        _pipeClient.Dispose();

        _isConnected = false;
    }

    private async void ListenForMessages() {
        if (!_pipeClient.IsConnected) {
            Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] Not connected to server");
            return;
        }

        Trace.WriteLine("[CLIENT] Checking for message");

        string message = await Task.Run(ss.ReadString);

        Trace.WriteLine($"[CLIENT] Message received: {message}");

        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            MessageLabel.Text = message;
        });

        ListenForMessages();
    }
}

Pipe server
namespace Server;

public partial class ServerPage : ContentPage {
    private readonly NamedPipeServerStream _pipeServer;
    private readonly StreamString ss;


    public ServerPage() {
        InitializeComponent();

        _pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
        ss = new StreamString(_pipeServer);

        InitPipeServer();
    }

    private void InitPipeServer() {
        _pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(ar => {
            _pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(ar);
            Trace.WriteLine("[SERVER] Client connected");
        }, null);
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing() {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        _pipeServer.Close();
        _pipeServer.Dispose();
    }

    private void SendMessage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!_pipeServer.IsConnected) {
            Trace.WriteLine("[SERVER] Not connected to client");
            return;
        }

        string message = MessageEntry.Text is null ? "null" : MessageEntry.Text;
        ss.WriteString(message);

        Trace.WriteLine($"[SERVER] Message `{message}` sent");
    }
}

Note: The Client and Server are both separate applications which start up at the same time.
I tried connecting using Connect() and ConnectAsync().
I've also looked everywhere for possible known issues about named pipes on MacOS, but without success.
It also doesn't throw any exceptions or anything like that.
EDIT: It works on .NET 7, but not on .NET 8

This looks like a potential issue on .NET 8 on MacOS while it works on .NET 7. And I also notice that you've logged a new issue on Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21874, you can follow up there.
